# Select active tab based on current controller and current object id in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tabs

In my Rails 3.2 app I want to assign a active class to list element based on current collection  being viewed.

In my helper method I have something like below

```
def active_nav_tab(classname)
    if controller.class == classname && controller.action_name == 'show'
       "class=active"
    end
end
```

It assigns the correct class at controller level to all the categories which are included in top navigation bar. How do I modify my helper method so that it selects only current collection as active.

And in my view layer

```
<% collections = Collection.all %>
        <% collections.each do |collection| %>
        <li <%= active_nav_tab(CollectionsController) %>>
          <%= link_to colection.name, collection %>
        </li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Question is a little unclear. What is `categories`? What do you mean by 'it assigns the correct class at controller level'? Clear details will help.

Comment: Let's say I visit a collection named 'news' which has all the posts which belongs to 'news' collection. these collection names are part of main navigation. My current code assigns the 'active' class to all the collections where I want to mark active to currently active collection. I hope this is bit clear now

Comment: Updated the answer below. Check if that helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying your *helper method* as this:

```
def active_nav_tab(classname)
    if params[:controller] == classname && params[:action] == 'show'
       "class=active"
    end
end
```

In view:

```
    <li <%= active_nav_tab(CollectionsController) %>>
```

**UPDATE**:
Suppose you clicked the *news* collection tab from the list. This takes you the `show` action, where you do something like:

```
@collection = Collection.find_by_name('news')
```

Now, in your view, you only want to show this collection as active tab. You can do that as:

// In your iteration of tab list:

```
<% collections = Collection.all %>
        <% collections.each do |collection| %>
        <li <%= "class='active'" if collection.eql?(@collection)  %>>
          <%= link_to collection.name, collection %>
        </li>
<% end %>
```

In this iteration, when 'news' collection is encountered, it will be same as the `@collection`, and `active` class will be added.

```
<li <%= "class='active'" if collection.eql?(@collection)  %>>
```

Hope this helps :)